# What's the difference between order_id and Parent_id in sales Order?

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, architecture

The question might look a bit stupid but I don't understand the difference between parent_id and order_id.

Comment: can you point the specific sales order table?

Comment: Well obviously order_id is your order id, but I'm not so sure on parent_id, I've never seen a child order

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.info.html
You can see parent_id at the beginnin and order_id above...
order_id is necessary for the invoice...
For sure increment_id is the showed order id but the difference between the other you is a mistery for me!

Comment: I guess the parent id will be in case the order was edited.

Comment: no because in Mgento you can't edit anything! when you edit an order the order will be deleted and created again with the order = "increaed_id"-1 .
Parent_id and order_id are counter form 1 to ... 
and the incrase togheter but of course there will be a case where they are different. i supposed

Comment: nop, when you edit any order, the previous one is cancelled and a new one is placed, you will find a link to old order in the new one, thats i guess where the parent id is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the order table itself there are two fields:

1. `relation_parent_id` - the entity_id of the original order before editing in admin,
2. `relation_parent_real_id` - the increment_id of the original order before editing in the admin,

So in these tables `relation_parent_id` will be the tables auto-increment something like `195` but `relation_parent_real_id` will be the Magento order increment something like `145000003`.

I am not sure why the soap api only talks about 1 but there are two in the table itself.

Answer (score 8):

`order_id` is the table increment id.
`parent_id` only has a value if you edit the order in the backend.
Here is how it works.

When you edit an order in the backend, the order is canceled and a new order is created, ending up with 2 orders.

In order to keep a link between these 2 orders, magento stores in the `parent_id` field of the second order the `order_id` of the original order.
That's why you will see on the second order view page in the backend a link to the original order.

Comment: nice information

Answer (score 0):

Order id is the unique key (primary key) of the order, while the Parent Id is used if the order is edited, the edited order will be cancelled and a new order will be placed, parent id will be then used as a reference to link both. Just as in the image below:

[image]